# Probabilistic graphical models applications

Tags: probability, optimization, conditional-probability, machine-learning

I have become a little bit confused about the applications of probabilistic graphical models. I search a lot, but I saw more theory information about PGMs rather than their application.
How can we use probabilistic graphical models for combinatorial optimization? If so, how? Are there any special algorithms?
Also, do PGMs have applications in natural language processing?

Comment: Give at least a reference for this not-very-common-object such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model

Comment: Yeah, I saw that before, but it didn't explain it enough